# Is there a way to properly continue this while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, reduce

I have written a function where the input is a list of numbers (items), where the length is a multiple of 3.

I want to this function to continue, until there is only 1 value left in items.

```
while len(items) > 1:
    for x in range(0, len(items), 3):
        if items[x] < items[x+1] < items[x+2] or items[x] > items[x+1] >items[x+2] :
            result.append(items[x+1])
        elif items[x+1] < items[x] < items[x+2] or items[x+1] > items[x] > items[x+2]:
            result.append(items[x])
        else:
            result.append(items[x+2])
        items = result
        break

return items
```

Comment: Is this an abstract challenge to write an equivalent algorithm using `reduce`, or are you asking whether using `reduce` is a good solution to this problem? The answer to the former is "yes, but it's not going to be pretty". The answer to the latter should be no.

Comment: I guess I'm just asking how I would keep reducing the input using the same algorithm, until I'm left with one element

Comment: it seems to not want to continue the algorithm past the initial for loop. It's reducing it down to the first number of the input. This is the input i'm working with: [99, 42, 17, 7, 1, 9, 12, 77, 15]

Comment: What happened to the line `result = []`, and where did the `break` come from?

Comment: with the result = [] and without break, that's when I get list index out of range error.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess at what you needed and how your code should appear...

```
items = [99, 42, 17, 7, 1, 9, 12, 77, 15]

while len(items) > 1:
    result = []
    for x in range(0, len(items), 3):
        a, b, c = items[x], items[x+1], items[x+2]
        if a < b < c or a > b >c :
            result.append(b)
        elif b < a < c or b > a > c:
            result.append(a)
        else:
            result.append(c)

    items = result

print(items)
```

Introducing the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` helped me better read the code.

Comment: this gave me all the correct results. but when put through my automated tester, it says it's incorrect /:

Comment: @BeanieLeung, then I think you need to edit your original question to include the requirements that were given to you.

Comment: That should be edited into your question, not as a comment. I have a few things I would look for: The auto-grader is probably expecting your function to **return** the result instead of print it. Should the result be the final list with one element in it, or the element inside that list? 3**0 = 1 is a power of 3 -- does this give the correct result for single element lists?

Comment: AH, I figured it out. this is the correct code, just had to convert to string after. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not quite right. Imagine a simple input of `[1, 1, 0]`. By looking at this, the median should be `1` but the use of `>` and `<` instead of `<=` and `>=` end up with the code entering the final `else` block because `1<1` is `False` and `1>1` is also `False`. The final else block sets the result equal to the third element, which is `0`.

Switch your operators to `>=` and `<=` to fix this. The `break` at the bottom of your for loop immediately breaks after one iteration, so that also needs to be removed.

If you have a list of one element (3**0 = 1), you will end up with an `IndexError` when you try to get the 2nd and 3rd elements in your loop.

So we need to

1. Switch operators to test for equality as well
2. Remove the erroneous break
3. Handle the base case

```py
def median_split3(items):
  if len(items) == 1: # Base Case
    return items[0] 
  while len(items) > 1:
    result = []
    for x in range(0, len(items), 3):
      a, b, c = items[x:x+3]
      if a <= b <= c or a >= b >= c:
        result.append(b)
      elif b <= a <= c or b >= a >= c:
        result.append(a)
      else:
        result.append(c)
    items = result
  return items[0]


test1 = [99, 42, 17, 7, 1, 9, 12, 77, 15]  
print(test1, "-->", median_split3(test1))

test2 = [1, 1, 0]
print(test2, "-->", median_split3(test2))

test3 = [0, 0, 1]
print(test3, "-->", median_split3(test3))

test4 = [9]
print(test4, "-->", median_split3(test4))
```

Output:

```
[99, 42, 17, 7, 1, 9, 12, 77, 15] --> 15
[1, 1, 0] --> 1
[0, 0, 1] --> 0
[9] --> 9
```